# Something like base_url from codeigniter for opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, base-url

Codeigniter has a function, `base_url()`

```
<?php echo base_url('/file')?>
```

that prints the absolute URL,

Is there any equivalent for Opencart?

Comment: `$this->config->get('config_url');`? **Edit:** It's a little different if using SSL: `$this->config->get('config_ssl');`

Comment: I don't think its the same, you mean using `$this->config->get('config_url').'/file'`  ??

Comment: Well, you could make your own `function` which just appends whatever parameter you pass it to the base URL, that's all that CodeIgniter's `base_url` is doing.

Comment: What are you needing to do this for exactly? May not need to do this at all

Comment: i want to work in local and production without having to adjust every time the urls..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look in the header.php controller file

```
 if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
     $this->data['base'] = $this->config->get('config_ssl');
  } else {
     $this->data['base'] = $this->config->get('config_url');
  }
```

Just call below from your template file.

```
<?php echo $base; ?>
```

Comment: Just to note that the $base variable will only be available in your `/catalog/view/theme/your-theme-name/template/common/header.tpl` not anywhere else

Comment: So there is no solution to use in the controllers?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet In controllers/models You use this `$this->config->get('config_[url|ssl]')`... The code *Jenson* picked is from header controller just to show You how to get the base URL... Now it is up on You to use it where You need it. But be aware that this base URL contains `http://yourdomain.com/` (for `config_url`) or `https://yourdomain.com/` (for `config_ssl`).